# How to compare two columns of two dataframes and indicate the changes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, one is current week's information, one is of last week.
I want to create a new dataset that lists all the changes during the week. Please see the following example:
if there is a change, indicates the change, otherwise leaves it as blank. If there is new item, indicates it is new.
[image]

I tried to compare these two columns, but I keep getting an error

```
can only compare identically-labelled series objects
```

Comment: The easiest way of accomplishing this would be to join the two dataframes using the ID columns and then compare the columns to check for changes.

Comment: Hi, Here is the my code, it does not work well. it returns whole list of past to current for the row that has change.       'df=pd.merge(current,past,how='left', on='ID')
df.columns.tolist()

conditions=[df['Rating _x']!=df['Rating_y'],
            df[‘Rating _x']==df['Rating _y']]

choices=[f"from: {df['Rating_y']} to: {df['Rating_x']}", " "]

change['Rating']=np.select(conditions,choices,default='NA')'

Comment: See my answer for an example with code.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

old = pd.DataFrame({
    "ID": ["AA", "BB", "CC"],
    "Rating": ["High", "Low", "Medium"],
    "Status": ["On track", "Monitor", "On track"]
})

new = pd.DataFrame({
    "ID": ["AA", "BB", "CC", "DD"],
    "Rating": ["Medium", "High", "Medium", "Low"],
    "Status": ["On track", "On track", "On track", "Monitor"]
})

(
    old
    # join the two dataframes used the ID column as a key
    .merge(new, how="outer", on="ID", suffixes=("_old", "_new"))
    # compare columns between old and new dataframe and assign new values
    .assign(
        Rating = lambda x: np.select(
            [x["Rating_new"].notna() & x["Rating_old"].isna(), x["Rating_new"] != x["Rating_old"]],
            ["New", "From '" + x["Rating_old"] +  "' To '" + x["Rating_new"] + "'"],
            default=np.nan
        ),
        Status = lambda x: np.select(
            [x["Status_new"].notna() & x["Status_old"].isna(), x["Status_new"] != x["Status_old"]],
            ["New", "From '" + x["Status_old"] +  "' To '" + x["Status_new"] + "'"],
            default=np.nan
        )
    )
    # select final columns
    .loc[:, ["ID", "Rating", "Status"]]
)
```

| ID | Rating | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | From 'High' To 'Medium' | nan |
| BB | From 'Low' To 'High' | From 'Monitor' To 'On track' |
| CC | nan | nan |
| DD | New | New |

Answer (score 0):

Please merge (left Join) the current table to previous table, Now you will have all the 4 columns in one dataframe. You can apply concatenate of columns to get desired results.

Please share dataframe creation code if you need help with code creat

Comment: The comparison code does not work.  The if statement gives me error" ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."                                                                                                              df=pd.merge(current,past,how='left', on='ID')
if df['Value1_x']==df['Value1_y']:
    change['Value1']=" "
else: 
     change['Value1']="Change from "+ df['value1_y'] +" To "+df['value1_x']

Answer (score 0):

Brute force, but it solves the problem. This might be a good start:

```
old = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3],"b":["a","b","c"],"c":["23-11","11-90",None]})
new = pd.DataFrame({"a":[9,2,3],"b":["a","x","y"],"c":["23-11",None,None]})
check = pd.DataFrame([], columns = ["a","b","c"])

for ix,row in new.iterrows():
    for col in new.columns:
        if new.loc[ix,col] != old.loc[ix,col]:
            check.loc[ix,col] = f"from: {old.loc[ix,col]} to: {new.loc[ix,col]}"
        else:
            check.loc[ix,col] = ""
```

old:

[image]

new:

[image]

check:

[image]